# Is there a lightweight IDE for C with nice visual design?

Tags: text-editor, ide, c, sublime-text, visual-studio-code

I am looking for an 'ideal' environment for writing and running simple C programs for beginners in programming. What I want is something that has an appealing design, like **Sublime Text 3** or **Visual Studio Code**, lightweight, in addition with the feature of creating the project folder automatically and also a straightforward building and running program with one click. It would be nice to see the output side-by-side with code.

The other way of saying what I need is a [repl.it](https://www.repl.it) with visual appearance of Sublime or Visual Code. Or some of these editors or similar, like Atom, with simple run button.

Software I know that is out there but don't have all of that features:

- Code::Blocks makes creating everything for project, but with too many steps and it's also not easy for setting a theme.
- Dev-C++ can create a mess when creating project by not creating a folder for it. 
  Also, the brackets completion is not good, it's easy to duplicate it and mess with 
  syntax. Some themes are available, but are not good as in Sublime, for example.
- It's possible to build C in Sublime, but it doesn't work with programs that need input.
- Visual Studio Code has built-in terminal, but user needs to create a folder and run gcc commands and this doesn't encourage him/her to experimenting enough.

Simply, I need a nice looking, easy to use tool, with no lagging, in order to achieve a good user experience for beginners that allow easy experimentation with C code.

**Additional question**

I think I'm gonna use Visual Studio Code integrated with Terminal. I was wondering if I can make some bash script (not sure if this the right thing I need) which would create a directory named with parameter and setting a variable so that using other script, user could run and compile the current working file. I think I can figure it out, I'm just not sure it will work properly.

Comment: What operating system would this need to run on?

Comment: Additional question - should be asked separately, and not on this site

Answer (score 3):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) (free, open source) is lite and allows it, but with some steps from user.

- user needs plugins: **Config Toolbar**, **External Tools** (all in Addon Manager)
- user needs to add a "tool" to compile code; and second "tool" to run compiled app. Via Tools menu (from plugin).
- and enter reg.ex. in "tool" properties (for both tools)
- user needs to add 2 buttons via Plugins / Config Toolbar (just call commands list there, find your "tools")
- to use "projects" user needs to work with **Project Manager** plugin (standard)

Better if you do all steps for user, and make CudaText zip, with plugins and config (in settings/ dir).
It can be .zip file which must be unpacked over CudaText.

Screenshot of External Tools dialog
[image: CudaText ExtTools]

Comment: Adding run button to an editor seems the right thing for me and design is good, but SmartScreen is preventing me from running it.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: It is false positive of Win8 (it finds malware? I use Linux build and don't know.)

Comment: I had to disable SmartScreen temporarily and run it. I'm not sure whether I will use it, since my students would need to disable it also. The project files are not wrapped into a folder and they could end with a mess of project and source files. I know its a detail, but it's important.

Comment: But I'm trying to set it up. Could you help me to set the compile tool? I selected gcc and in Parameters I tried different things, like `-o "{FileNameNoExt}" "{FileName}"`. But nothing happens, no output and no executable created.

Comment: Let's talk in CudaText forum, so I can give details.

Comment: "not wrapped into a folder" - Project Manager plugin allows to add any files+dirs from any disks. So what to put into new folder?

Comment: Ok, I created a topic on 'Bugs, Issues' section. It's called 'CudaText: how to make a gcc compiler tool? '

Comment: Yes, it has nice options, like adding all files on editor into the project. But those files are mixed with other files (source files and CudaText other project files). I know that user just needs to be careful, but in Codeblocks and Visual Studio 2017, when you create a project, it creates a file and a directory for it, so files from different projects will not be mixed. I think it's important because users that are learning programming have to focus on essentials of the problem, others things must be automatic, as possible.

Comment: @user162208 But we can't make new folder for project: user adds _existing_ folders to project and he don't make new ones, ie he makes new ones in existing folders (which added to project).

Comment: Pls see http://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Project_Manager

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that's the problem. User saves a new project as a `.cuda-proj` file. Later, for example, if user doesn't change directory, he saves a source file and then starts new project, saving again as `.cuda-proj`. All of these files are in the same directory and if user change the order of files in Explorer, everything gets badly organized. Only opening project in CudaText user can see what is attached to what. All relies on the fact that I need a project first, to later add files.

Comment: While in Codeblocks, it creates a hello world file already inside a folder and all files added later will be on this folder. It's much more organized and requires less actions from user.

Comment: In CudaText, It's possible to save first all in one directory and add to project, but it requires discpline from user and more actions, since user has to create the directory manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82684/discussion-between-user162208-and-rprogram).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Geany](https://www.geany.org/).

Both free and Free, builds available for Linux, Windows, and OS X, has plugins for all sorts of stuff, and has configurable-by-file-extension "build", "compile" and "run" buttons/menus.